# IndexError: List index out of range.. despite being within range?

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling, path, index-error

thanks in advance for your help.

I'm running into an issue with the following piece of code:

```
category = path.split("/")[3]
label = int(category.split("_")[0][1]) 
y.append(label)
```

The error is as follows: IndexError: list index out of range. The error comes on the first line, when I do the split. I (think) I understand what the error is implying, but when I do len(path) I get 33 ... so [3] shouldn't give a problem.

I tested this following snippet of code to understand split better:

```
txt = "welcome to the jungle"
x = txt.split()[2]
print(x)
```

For the code above, the output is "the" as expected as it's the [2] entry.

Now, back to my code, when I run:

```
x = path.split()
print(x)
```

I get the following output:

```
['.\\00\\01_palm\\frame_00_01_0001.png']
```

The code which I'm having an issue with is from a public GitHub project I am recreating on my local machine (Jupyter). When I run the same project on Google Colab I have no issues. But when I'm doing it locally I run into this.

Question 1) Can someone explain to me why the code uses: path.split("/")[3] ? Why "/"? The actual path as seen from the output only has "\", does "/" mean something else? Sorry I'm very new to python.

Question 2) What can I do to fix the "IndexError: list index out of range"?

Thank you

Comment: `len(path)` is the number of characters in the path. When you split it on `/` you get a list of substrings, and the length of that list is equal to the number of `/` in that path plus one. That list will only have a valid index of `3` if there were at least three `/` in the path. Finally, note that forward slash `/` is not the same as backslash.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear from the code that on `Github`, it's path is intended for `Linux` machine for which the path separator is `/`, but you are running it on `windows` for which the path separator is `\\` so you have to modify your code as,

```
category = path.split("\\")[3]
label = int(category.split("_")[0][1]) 
y.append(label)
```

For any machine, if you want to see the path separator then you can do

```
import os
print(os.path.sep)
```

For `Linux` system, output will be:

```
/
```